# Internal and External Blog

Tags: blog

My company is looking to start an internal company blog that only our employees have access to.  We are looking at Sharepoint and other options to do this, one of which is WordPress.  (Not everyone in our office has Sharepoint, but my questions on that will be going elsewhere.)

There is the possibility that we will also want an external, public blog at some point.

Can we have both a private company blog and a public blog with WordPress?

And if anyone has enough knowledge to compare, what would the pros and cons be for Sharepoint vs WordPress?

Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: Sharepoint and WordPress are _very_ different animals. Any comparison is going to be pretty sketchy.

Comment: I understand that they are very different.  My question was mainly whether or not a private and public blog could be set up with both/either.  =)

Comment: Yes, you create an internal website by hosting it on a machine on your LAN.  Your public site, depending on the size of your company is likely to be hosted on a domain host/service provider.

If you are the person that will be working on both, I presume you would rather use the same tool for both, in that case WordPress is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we have both a private company blog and a public blog with WordPress?

Yes, but it depends on how you define private.  We use WP multisite subdomains.  We have over 200 sites, most of them public.  But we have a few sites that are "private" - requires user to login.  Additionally the user has to have been registered with the site.

You can achieve this using a plugin.  We wrote our own but there are many out there, for example - http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/private-only